# Need SQL Query Help Please

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query :

```
SELECT
wp_posts.post_author,
wp_posts.post_date,
wp_posts.post_title,
wp_posts.post_content,
wp_posts.post_excerpt,
wp_posts.guid,
wp_posts.post_name AS slug,
wp_posts.ID AS wp_post_id,
wp_posts.post_status,
wp_sfmembers.display_name,
wp_postmeta.meta_key,
wp_postmeta.meta_value
FROM
wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_sfmembers ON wp_posts.post_author = wp_sfmembers.user_id
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
where post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post'
ORDER BY post_date DESC
```

The result is this
[image]

What I would Like is this:
[image]

I just want to combine the wp_postmeta into one record. I hope this makes sense.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: According to your query, `wp_postmeta` is a table, and according to your question you "want to combine the wp_postmeta into one record" - do you mean you want to concatenate `meta_key` and `meta_value`, or do you want to combine the values of (say) `meta_value` into one result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. It does assume you only want the specific meta_key values that I've listed in the where clause. This does fit your example, as you are excluding all meta_key values other than what is in that list. It also assumes the meta_key values in your example are the same that need to be brought up as columns every time.

```
select wp_posts.post_author,
       wp_posts.post_date,
       wp_posts.post_title,
       wp_posts.post_content,
       wp_posts.post_excerpt,
       wp_posts.guid,
       wp_posts.post_name        as slug,
       wp_posts.id               as wp_post_id,
       wp_posts.post_status,
       wp_sfmembers.display_name,
       min(case when meta_key = '_edit_lock' then wp_postmeta.meta_key end) as meta_key,
       min(case when meta_key = '_edit_lock' then wp_postmeta.meta_value end) as meta_value,
       min(case when meta_key = '_yoast_wpseo_focuskw' then wp_postmeta.meta_value end) as meta_focus,
       min(case when meta_key = '_yoast_wpseo_title' then wp_postmeta.meta_value end) as meta_title,
       min(case when meta_key = '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc' then wp_postmeta.meta_value end) as meta_desc
  from wp_posts
  join wp_sfmembers
    on wp_posts.post_author = wp_sfmembers.user_id
  join wp_postmeta
    on wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id
 where post_status = 'publish'
   and post_type = 'post'
   and meta_key in ('_edit_lock','_yoast_wpseo_focuskw','_yoast_wpseo_title','_yoast_wpseo_metadesc')
group by   wp_posts.post_author,
           wp_posts.post_date,
           wp_posts.post_title,
           wp_posts.post_content,
           wp_posts.post_excerpt,
           wp_posts.guid,
           wp_posts.post_name,
           wp_posts.id,
           wp_posts.post_status,
           wp_sfmembers.display_name
 order by  post_date desc
```

Comment: Hello, the code you wrote was very helpful but when I import the data into my new DB I get several errors and the post_content shows up as Chinese symbols . I am importing into an MsSQL DB,  ntext field.

Comment: That is likely some sort of issue that occurred when exporting and importing into your new database (unrelated to the query)